# Java Files.walkTree() sub directory problem

Tags: java, linux, java.nio.file

My platform is Centos 7.0, I'm working in Java 8.

My question is how java.nio.file,Files.walkFileTree() should be used to look for files in a directory tree that contains some files and directories that the current user is not permitted to access, but which contains many other directories and files that are accessible. This diagram shows the kind of patter I have, dirs and files in other groups, but usually world accessible (755) so my program can see them. However the presence of one no accessible (750) directory seems to foul up traversal. diagram shows simplifed view.

```
a 755
|----- ab 755
        | ----- f1 644  <== files here found
        | ----- f2 644
|----- ac 750           <== dir not accessible
        | ----- f3 644 .<== expect not to find this
|----- ad 755
|       | ----- f4 644  <== expect to find, but not seen
```

I'm still investigating, but it appears that my application is failing when the directory traversal hits a directory whose permissions deny access. I'm in the process of producing a cut-down example, but in the meantime I would like to check that these expectations are reasonable:

1. walkFileTree() will attempt to visit every sub directory
2. If it hits a directory or file that cannot be accessed visitFileFailed() call back will be called and if that function returns a value of CONTINUE then the traversal will continue - there are other options for the return value, but for now that's all need.
3. I should not need to verify file permissions in these callbacks

I'm using Files.walkFileTree() rather than Files.find() because the latter also seems to fail when hitting unreadable directories and I thought walkFileTree() would give me more control.

```
FileVisitor<Path> visitor = new FileVisitor<Path>() {

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, 
                            BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        // do I need to code something like this?           
        if ( ! dir.toFile().canRead() 
            || ! dir.toFile().canExecute()
                            ) {

                return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
        } else {        
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        // code here where I action some files, which works if I get here.      

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        // log error here, but carry on down the tree
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        if ( exc != null) {
               // log error, but carry on anyway
               // in my tests we never arrive here
        }           
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

};

EnumSet<FileVisitOption> opts = EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);

try {           
    Files.walkFileTree(new File(filePath).toPath(), 
                           opts, 
                           Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
                           visitor);


} catch(Exception e) {
    // log errror here, but in my tests we don't end up here
}
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Can you give an example of the file/directory structure? If you don't have read access to a directory, you can't list its contents

Comment: @Joni tried to explain with diagram added. I don't expect to descend into directories with no execute access, but as first sight it seems like the whole traversal stops when it hits such a directory, I was expecting to skip non-accessible directories.

Comment: There where you say "// do I need to code something like this?" have you tried coding something like this?

Comment: @Mike Nakis: yes, my code has that, but looking at the sample it seems not to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

A cut down version of my program works as I expect.

The [sample here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Find.java) also works in my test environment. Non accessible directories do not obstruct the traversal to accessible directories.

As to why my full program fails, I have no explanation ...